# react-leaflet WMSTileLayer 'params' option causes map layer to flicker when any unrelated state variable is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, wms

I am using react-leaflet:3.2.0 to display a WMS tile layer using the WMSTileLayer component.  It works beautifully provided I don't include the [`params`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/) option.  If I include anything via the `params` option then updating ANY state variable causes the layer to flicker.

In the example below, I hard code `params={{hello:'world'}}` into the WMSTileLayer options, and every time I press a button to update a completely unrelated state variable called `dummy` the map flickers.  Since I potentially have a lot of state management going on it prevents me from using the `params` option with WMSTileLayer.  And since I really need to use the `params` option to add arguments to the WMS query string, I'm stuck.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Presumably others use this option OK.

All help greatly appreciated, thanks!

[Here is a link to a gif illustrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLbeP.gif) and the code is show below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { WMSTileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'
import * as L from 'leaflet'
import 'proj4leaflet'
import proj4 from 'proj4'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'
import { Button } from 'react-bulma-components';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

export default function Dataset(props) {

  const zoomLevel = 1
  const center = [51.7, -1.5]
  const projName = 'EPSG:27700'
  const projParams = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs'
  const crs27700 = new L.Proj.CRS(projName,
    projParams,
    {
      resolutions: [896, 448, 224, 112, 56, 28, 14, 7, 3.5, 1.75, 0.875, 0.4375, 0.21875, 0.109375],
      origin: [-238375, 1376256]
    }
  )
  proj4.defs(projName,projParams)

  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(true)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="dataset-container">
        <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoomLevel} crs={crs27700} attributionControl={false} >
          <WMSTileLayer
            layers={'pollutant'}
            url={`/mapserver/mapserv?map=/maps/pollutant.map&year=05`}
            params={{hello:'world'}} // <-- comment out this line to stop the map flickering when the button is pressed
            maxZoom={6}
            transparent={true}
            format='image/png'
            opacity={0.8}
          />
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
      <Button onClick={e => setDummy(!dummy)}>Press me</Button>{dummy ? ' dummy=true' : ' dummy=false'}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/825#issuecomment-765349582:

> This is the expected behavior that props comparison is made by reference, it's up to you to keep track of these references rather than creating new objects in every render as you need.

The actual issue in the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68602300) above is re-creation of the params object on every re-render. You can prevent that by using the [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook, for example:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { MapContainer, WMSTileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

export default function App() {
  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(true);

  const layerParams = useMemo(() => {
    return {hello: 'world'};
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <MapContainer
          style={{ height: "400px", width: "600px" }}
          center={[51.7, -1.5]}
          zoom={13}
        >
          <WMSTileLayer
            layers={"TOPO-OSM-WMS"}
            url={`http://ows.mundialis.de/services/service?`}
            params={layerParams}
          />
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
      <button onClick={(e) => setDummy(!dummy)}>Press me</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this but could find no answer. I tried abstracting the WMS to a separate function component but the result was the same. I reproduced the problem using a publicly accessible WMS and default CRS with less code so posting here in case useful to someone else investigating:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { MapContainer, WMSTileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

export default function App() {

  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(true)
  
  return (<>
    <div>
      <MapContainer style={{height:"400px", width:"600px"}} center={[51.7, -1.5]} zoom={13} >
        <WMSTileLayer
          layers={'TOPO-OSM-WMS'}
          url={`http://ows.mundialis.de/services/service?`}
          params={{hello:'world'}} // <-- comment out this line to stop the map flickering when the button is pressed
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
    <button onClick={e => setDummy(!dummy)}>Press me</button>
  </>)
```